# How to make draft like gmail in outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

How to make draft like gmail in outlook 2007?

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6587

I just want to make reday to use email template with body text,already filled email addresses in To, cc , bcc field. and subject line.

and then want to use this template to use send email quickly whenever i need

Comment: gee, perhaps I should make my answers less descriptive *eyeroll*

Comment: no the link of article provided by maptol described nicely whole process.

Comment: Ah, I guess I described the steps in white font/invisible ink then. Thank you very much.

Comment: Linkrot happens. If the link in the accepted answer stops working, the answer becomes worthless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use templates feature](http://www.ehow.com/how_2064447_create-template-outlook-2007.html)

> 1. Open Outlook 2007. Make sure you have an active account fully
>      configured and ready to send email.
> 2. Write an email message. Select "New" from the main toolbar.
> 3. Customize the email. Add the intended recipients to the "To" and
>      "CC," including any groups. Enter a
>      subject line for the template.
>      Finally, add content to the message
>      and apply any formatting.
> 4. Save the email as a template. Select the "Office" button, and then
>      "Save As" in the "Save as type"
>      drop-down list. Select "Outlook
>      Template." Give the template a name,
>      and choose a file location, or accept
>      the default folder of "Templates."
>      Click "Save."
> 5. Use the template. To send an email based on the template, select "Tools,"
>      and then "Forms." From there, select
>      "Choose a Form." From the "Look In"
>      drop-down list, select "User Templates
>      in File System." Navigate to the
>      location where you saved the theme if
>      it isn't in the "Templates" folder.
>      Select your template. Make any
>      changes, such as updating the message
>      body content or subject line, or
>      adding or removing recipients, and
>      then click "Send."

Comment: i forgot link which maptol added it was not right i found my answer  in another link of that page this is link where i got my answer http://blogs.msdn.com/outlook/archive/2008/11/10/living-in-outlook-message-templates.aspx. so ur answer is closet to this link. so i'm going to change my accepted answer

Comment: I liked this extra info in article "You can open the file in the Windows File Explorer"

Answer (score 1):

Using the power of google:
http://blogs.msdn.com/outlook/archive/2008/11/17/living-in-outlook-advanced-message-templates.aspx